# Laundry Room Floor Drain

Tags: drain

When the spin/drain cycle on my washing machine occurs, the floor drain overflows and water is all over the floor.

Comment: Likely a tree root or other blockage problem on your main line, but a birds nest in a vent pipe can do it too.

Comment: State your question.  Questions end in question marks.

Comment: What make and model is the washer? Do any other drains work?

Answer (score 0):

Have had a similar problem . It began when new so no roots. My utility room is at the opposite end of the house about 80 ft with a few turns,  from where the house sewer leaves the pad to go the municipal sewer. Even with the required minimum pitch on the sewer line , the very large volume of water discharged from the washer will back up into the floor drain rather than run fast enough down the long sewer line. I put a commercial  rubber stopper in the floor drain . It has worked for almost 20 years. When it first happened I called a plumber ; he cut into the drywall to put his "snake" down the sewer clean-out at the washer , he found no restriction. He apparently did not understand what the problem was. Had the city put the sewer tie at the other side of the lot , it would have only been 8 ft to the edge of the pad.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not cure this problem, I would, as a last resort, install  a laundry/drain pump system. I found one "on-line" at Amazon.com; a Zoeller #105-0001 system for $208.00 that included free shipping. You can also try Lowes and Home Depot or any building supply in your area. I have seen them used in apartments my wife and I have previously rented. You could also dump the water into a laundry tub that will more slowly drain into the drain line. You could also adapt the laundry sink drain to drain the water as slowly as necessary to keep the drain from overflowing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a clasped sewer ling or you simple routine drain line snaking may solve the issue.  Either way a good router guy should be able to solve the issue.